# How to use the antishake option for iMovie

Tags: macos, video, imovie, video-editing

I have a .mp4 video clip recorded with a GoPro camera, that I like to stabilize. I want to use iMovie, which I understand should have an antishake function according to [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14719) information.

In iMovie I apperently can't chose the antishake function, I can see the icon, but it's grey and can't be selected?

Does anybody know the reason for this and how to fix it? I dont want to buy new software and would prefer to use iMovie.

As an extra info, I use Yosemite and Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if anyone is still looking for the answer to this but as far as yosemite is concerned these answers are wrong.  You simply drag the clip or movie into the timeline as normal and click either the entire clip or section that you want and then you click on enhance.  Once you do that you now make sure to click on the video camera icon and the option for Stabilize Shaky Video will show and you can select it

Comment: The OP stated they were using Yosemite, and solved it themselves in one of the other answers. Not sure how the OP stating they solved it can be "wrong".

Answer (score 2):

Via http://www.wondershare.com/imovie/stabilize-shaky-videos-in-imovie.html:

> Choose a video clip either from the Event browser or project. You can apply the Analyze for stabilization to the whole event or just to the video clips you want to apply. You can stabilize the video clips first, and then drag them to the project or stabilize the video clips in the project. You can go to **File > Analyze Video > Stabilization** from the iMovie menu to stabilize the video.

Comment: I did find that answer to, I guess I must be using a newer version of iMovie, 'cause I have no "file" option in the top bar also I can't select stabilizing when uploading the video to iMovie?

Comment: I should probably update mine then

Answer (score 1):

Well, found the answer myself. The mistake was, that it's not enough to import the clip you want to edit, it needs to be included into an event. The procedure is therefor:

1. Create "Create New", which is a container for the video to be uploaded.
2. Import video into the container just created.

Now the video can be edited with antishake.

Hope the information will be helpfull to others.